# In spring boot java project how to map a property of different data types from a mongo DB to java class?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, objectmapper

Hi i have a mongo DB ducument section which has the columns property as shown (1st format)

```
   "columns" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "itemId" : ObjectId("5b863b50083ae5eb1e678d75"), 
                            "type" : "field"
                        }
                    ], 
                    [
                        {
                            "itemId" : ObjectId("5b8d4404af0963f54e262f46"), 
                            "type" : "field"
                        }
                    ], 
                    [

                    ], 
                    [

                    ]
                ]


which is of the type Array of Array of Objects 

However at some places it is also stored in this format as well . (2nd format)


          "columns" : [
            {
                "0" : {
                    "itemId" : "5b863b50083ae5eb1e678d75", 
                    "type" : "field"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "0" : {
                    "itemId" : "5b8d4404af0963f54e262f46", 
                    "type" : "field"
                }
            }, 
            {

            }, 
            {

            }
        ]
```

As Array of Object of Object

now i have dao class someObject to store the inner most object

```
public class SomeObject{

private ObjectId itemId;
    private String type;
    public ObjectId getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }
    public void setItemId(ObjectId itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

here is the section Dao class

```
public class Section{

private List<List<SomeObject>> columns;

    public List<List<someObject>> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(List<List<SomeObject>> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}
```

how section class ever this works fine for first format as i have taken type as List

but breaks for second format as it has diffeferent

i also tried using this class

```
Public class Section {

private List<Object> columns;

}
```

this mapps the second format but breaks for first format 
i got the following error

```
 "exceptionDetails": "Cannot convert [Document{{itemId=5877f2345449aef957e1d8ec, type=field}}] of type class java.util.ArrayList into an instance of class java.lang.Object! Implement a custom Converter<class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.Object> and register it with the CustomConversions.
```

please can anyone suggest how do i create by dao class such that it can map both the formats ?? do i need to implement custom mapper ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are a little do not understand what is [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) class. What you have are [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

And about your question, as you noticed and as reported in the exception details your document is an `ArrayList`, why not just read it as an `ArrayList` and then set it to `Section` field? 
But if this option does not suit you, you can implement [Custom Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters), this is also reported to you in the exception details.

Comment: i am not sure if it will be an Array of ArrayList (as in format 1 ) or an array of Objects( as shown in format 2)

Comment: @user_531 then can it be worthwhile to put your data in order and save them in one format?